# Implementing row wise operation using output of last row in pyspark

Tags: sql, excel, pyspark, state

I want to implement this state change function in pyspark but cannot access the output of the previous row to apply the function to the next row.

[image]

Above is the screenshot where the current row is calculated by the mode of the current and next row's input and the output of the previous row.

Is there any way to implement this in pyspark?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: To do this with pyspark you'll need a column to sort on, a window function and some logic to calculate the mode as this is not a build-in function of pyspark. If you only have 1's and 2's in your inp column then you can get away with more efficient logic than mode (if sum(inp)>4 then 2 else 1).